# How to check for duplicate value in Select options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have 6 Select input fields and all the 6 input fields have same options value, but  i want that each of select input value should be unique for e.g

> **Input 5 and Input 6 are optional input field but if they are filled then they should be validated for unique value**

```
Input1   Input2   Input3  Input4   Input5  Input6   

value1   value1   value1  value1   value1  value1
value2   value2   value2  value2   value2  value2
value3   value3   value3  value3   value3  value3
```

Now if user selected `value1` in `Input1` then he can't choose `value1` in other `select fields`

I know i can do it using `if elseif else` but it will not be that professional, is there a better way of validating it.

Comment: where you planning to validate at client side or server side ?

Comment: I just want a way to easily do this, then i will go for both server and browser side

Comment: This sound like plain use of javascript/jquery. Tip:`change('')` http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all input of fields in one variable, and then get only unique values.

Please see below. This will help.

```
if ($_POST) {
  $validate_data = [];
  $is_valid = FALSE; 
  $validate_data[] = $_POST['Input1'];
  $validate_data[] = $_POST['Input2'];
  $validate_data[] = $_POST['Input3'];
  $validate_data[] = $_POST['Input4'];

  // get unique elements from array
  $result = array_unique($validate_data);
  // if array size is equal to no of input fields then means all are unique
  // else it has duplicate values
  if (count($result) != 4 ) {
     $is_valid = FALSE;
  } else {
     // Validate optional fields
     if (isset($_POST['Input5']) && in_array($_POST['Input5'], $result)) {
         $is_valid = FALSE;
      } else if (isset($_POST['Input6']) && in_array($_POST['Input6'], $result)) {
         $is_valid = FALSE;
      } else {
         $is_valid = TRUE;
      }
  }

  echo ($is_valid) ? 'All are unique.' : 'Invalid Data';
}
```

Comment: As i told, 2 fields are optional what if user submitted only 4 fields or what he submitted only 5.

Comment: @AniketSingh Updated my answer to handle optional fields

Answer (score 1):

This is something I came up with, but it is not the best way of doing this.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $data = [];
    $data[] = $_POST['Input1'];
    $data[] = $_POST['Input2'];
    $data[] = $_POST['Input3'];
    $data[] = $_POST['Input4'];

    //optional values
    if ("" == trim($_POST['Input5'])) {
        $data[] = $_POST['Input5'];
    }
    if ("" == trim($_POST['Input6'])) {
        $data[] = $_POST['Input6'];
    }

    //count post elements
    $count = count($data);

    // get unique elements from array
    $result = array_unique($data);

    if (count($result) !== $count) {
        echo 'Duplicated data';
    } else {
        echo 'All are unique';
    }
}
```

I  think a better solution would be to look into some Javascript Validators

> Don't Reinvent The Wheel, Unless You Plan on Learning More About Wheels